# UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denies Ios

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, vuforia, access-denied

I know this has come up some time but I am not able to solve the error with any of the solutions I tried.

I just started testing my application - to save a screenshot to ios device Code is -

```
string GetiPhoneDocumentsPath()
{
    string path = Application.dataPath.Substring(0, Application.dataPath.Length - 5);
    path = path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf("/"));
    return path + "/Documents/";
}

string CreateImagesDirectory(string documentsPath) {
    //System.IO.File.SetAttributes (documentsPath, FileAttributes.Normal);
    string imagePath = documentsPath +"magicimages/";
    if (Directory.Exists(imagePath)) {return imagePath;}
    DirectoryInfo t = new DirectoryInfo(documentsPath);
    //Directory.CreateDirectory(imagePath);
    t.CreateSubdirectory("magicimages");
    System.IO.File.SetAttributes (imagePath, FileAttributes.Normal);

    return imagePath;
}
```

To wite the file

```
    Debug.Log("Do nothing actually as we need to save to persistent data path");
        string documentsPathIphone = GetiPhoneDocumentsPath();
        Debug.Log ("document path" + documentsPathIphone);
        string imagePath = CreateImagesDirectory (documentsPathIphone);
        //Path = imagePath + fileName;
        Debug.Log ("path iphone" + Path);
        Debug.Log("Appllicarion data path -->" + Application.dataPath);
        //string savepath = Application.dataPath.Replace ("game.app/Data", "/Documents/");
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes (System.IO.Path.Combine(Path , fileName), screenshot);
```

Assuming screenshot is bytes[]

I get the exception that as in subject. I am using Unity.

Error that I get is -

> UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   "/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9DA2D489-2037-451E-87D1-FA7354ECD0D1/Documents"
>   is denied.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You save with `Application.persistentDataPath` **not** `Application.dataPath`. Note that you must create a folder and save inside that folder instead of saving directly to this path.

So the final path you save to should be:

`Application.persistentDataPath+"Yourfolder/YourFileNale.extension"`.

or

`Application.persistentDataPath+"Documents/YourFileNale.extension"`.

Always use `Path.Combine` to Combine paths instead of `"+"` I used above.

Comment: Before I can create the directory I get the error in CreateImagesDirectory() so even the folder creation is not happening

Comment: What do you expect me to do if you get an error and don't post it?  ............  `if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(yourPath)))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(yourPath));
        }`...... then ....... `File.WriteAllBytes(yourPath, yourData);`

Comment: ok, I updated the methods with the code and error that I am getting. the exists option is available in CreateImagesDirectory method. Can you please check now?

Comment: You also need to add **Edit** and add the new code ans also mention the line of coed that's causing that error.

Comment: I solved it actually now. The issue was with datapath vs persistentdata path. using persistent one resolved the issue. Thanks anyways

Comment: This is what I said in my answer. I said you should use `Application.persistentDataPath` **not** `Application.dataPath`. I don't know what you have been using since then.